# GoogleMaps don't run in my cordova app

Tags: jquery, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am working on Visual Studio 2013 Apache Cordova App. I have a problem with locating a point on google maps. I have added the geolocation plugin in my app but it doesn't work. Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><button id="showmap" >show map </button></div>
    <div id="googleMap">View Map ---</div>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <script>

        $("#showmap").click(function () {
            var damas = new google.maps.LatLng(33.513, 36.2920000000003);
            var mapProp = {
                center: damas,
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
            var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: damas,
                radius: 20000,
                strokeColor: "#0F00FF",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#F0F0FF",
                fillOpacity: 0.8,
                editable: true
            });

            myCity.setMap(map);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please give me some advice. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to set a dimension for your `googleMap` div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add height to your div:

```
<div id="googleMap" style="height:300px;">View Map ---</div>
```

Or if you prefer you can set it when you click on show map button:

```
$("#googleMap").height(300);
```

[Here](http://js.do/code/79503) you can see an example that I've created for you.

Comment: yes its working i forgot to add style to my div . thank you very much .